# Synfusion: How to add Custom sorting in GridGroupedColumns GridSortColumnDescriptor

Tags: c#, asp.net, syncfusion

I want to sort grouped columns of syncfusion Grid in my way, for that i have created a derived class by extending `GridSortColumnDescriptor`

```
[DataContract()]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(ReviewerGridGroupingColumnSort)),XmlInclude(typeof(SynfusionCustomGridSorting))]
    public class SynfusionCustomGridSorting : GridSortColumnDescriptor
    {
        private  ReviewerGridGroupingColumnSort _sortGroupColumn= new ReviewerGridGroupingColumnSort ();
        public SynfusionCustomGridSorting()
        {
            this.ShouldSerialize();
            _sortGroupColumn.SortColumnName =this.Name;
            this.Comparer = _sortGroupColumn;

        }


    }
```

`ReviewerGridGroupingColumnSort` is my custom sorting class.

Every thing is working fine but at the end i am getting this exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The type
>   MarketWorkFlowWebApp.Common.SynfusionCustomGridSorting was not
>   expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types
>   that are not known statically. at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterGridEngine.Write13_SortColumnDescriptor(String
>   n, String ns, SortColumnDescriptor o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean
>   needType) at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterGridEngine.Write45_GridTableDescriptor(String
>   n, String ns, GridTableDescriptor o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean
>   needType) at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterGridEngine.Write48_GridEngine(String
>   n, String ns, GridEngine o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType) at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterGridEngine.Write49_GridEngine(Object
>   o)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Custom sorting can be performed using **GridGroupingControl.TableDescriptor.SortedColumns.Changing** event. By using this event you can use the custom comparer and perform custom sorting. Please refer the below online documentation link for more details regarding custom sorting.

**Documentation Link:** http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/asp.net/default.htm#!documents/customsorting.htm

Please let us know if you have any other questions or concerns.